# Who are the look-alikes hired by Abed supposed to be?

Tags: plot-explanation, reference, community

In *Community* season 3 episode 12 'Contemporary Impressionists', when Troy returns to his flat and sees Abed sat down with a leg cast, he fears the worst and then a Robin Williams lookalike appears.

Troy then goes to his blanket bedroom and says "Get out!" and four lookalikes appear.

The last two are clearly Julia Roberts and Tom Cruise.

But who are the first two characters (on the left in the picture) supposed to be and what films are they from?

[image: Three men standing in front of Abed]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The guy holding two lobsters is Woody Allen playing the part of Alvy Singer from [Annie Hall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075686/).

[image: Woody Allen]

The second guy is Rutger Hauer as Roy Batty from [Blade Runner](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083658/).

[image: Roy Batty]

Comment: Cheers, the lookalikes were not as convincing as the others, this was bugging me for a while.